# SQL Pivot / Case Query based on Row Value

Tags: sql-server, join, pivot, subquery

**Problem**

Using SQL Server, I'm trying to pivot data based on values in a column.   I want to move Bob and John's value column over if `Salary` is in the metric column.

Sample data:

`Person` table

```
Person    ID
-------------
Bob       1
Bob       1
John      2
John      2
```

`Value` table

```
Metric   Value    ID
---------------------
Age      52       1
Salary   60000    1
Age      45       2
Salary   55000    2
```

**Expected output**

My goal is to pivot the table if salary is present in the `Metric` column.

```
Person    Metric   Value   Salary   ID
---------------------------------------
Bob       Age      52      60000    1
John      Age      45      55000    2
```

Current code:

```
SELECT *
FROM person_table pt, value_table vb
WHERE pt.id = vb.id
  AND vb.metric IN ('Age', 'Salary')
```

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: @DannySlor Microsoft SQL Server - sorry will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    pt.Person,
    'Age' AS Metric,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vb.Metric = 'Age'    THEN vb.Value END) AS Value,
    MAX(CASE WHEN vb.Metric = 'Salary' THEN vb.Value END) AS Salary,
    pt.ID
FROM person_table pt
INNER JOIN value_table vb
    ON pt.id = vb.id
GROUP BY
    pt.Person,
    pt.ID
ORDER BY
    pt.ID;
```